# maximum line length in python

Tags: python, emacs

Should i still follow the rule of maximum line length of 79 char while coding in python.

if yes
 so when to use enter and \ for line breaking.

eg,

```
qy = MyModel.objects.filter(name='abcd', modified_on__range=
                                         (now-delta_6, now),type=1) \
                                         .select_related('Author')
```

I use emacs for my python coding. 
so when i use enter for line breacking sometime i can use tab for indentation and sometime i have to use \ for indentation

so what the best way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)?

Comment: You're breaking at very arbitrary columns... Why don't you break at the commas, for example? Also, seeing that this line is so long, why do you actually perform the call to `select_related` in that very line?

Comment: PEP 8 was written in 2001. Things have changed since then. I don't think it's a problem to have lines longer than 80 characters.

Comment: @Julian: PEP 8 is updated regularly.  The last update was less than two weeks ago.  It is intentional that it still includes the 79-character recommendation.  Of course it's up to you  whether you want to follow it.  I find it makes the code more readable.

Comment: The character limit can still be useful because sometimes you're reading the code on a small screen or without a second monitor.

Answer (score 7):

A maximum line length of 79 characters is recommended by PEP 8, and I usually don't find it too hard to follow this recommendation.

Also in accordance with PEP 8, I try to rely on the implied line continuation inside parentheses.  The given example can be easily split into two statements:

```
qy = MyModel.objects.filter(
    name='abcd', modified_on__range=(now - delta_6, now),type=1)
qy = qy.select_related('Author')
```

If your code performs a lot of method chaining, you might prefer to add a pair of parens to get implicit line continuation:

```
qy = (MyModel.objects
      .filter(name='abcd', modified_on__range=(now - delta_6, now),type=1)
      .select_related('Author'))
```

This puts every chained method on a line of its own, making it easy to see the steps involved at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite your code like this if you want to follow the PEP 8 guidelines:

```
qy = MyModel.objects.filter(name='abcd',
                            modified_on__range=(now-delta_6, now),
                            type=1).select_related('Author')
```

As for whether you should following the maximum line length suggested in PEP 8, that is really up to you.

PEP 8 is designed to improve readability of Python code, and the 79 character line length is for compatibility with certain width limited devices and for easy side-by-side code viewing.  I have pretty wide screens so even though I try to follow PEP 8 most of the time, this is one rule that I will ignore if I feel splitting up the line decreases readability.